# Starting a process as a subprocess in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that uses multiple worker processes (a pre-forking model) with the following code.

```
from  multiprocessing import Process
for i in range(0,3):
    Process(target=worker, args=(i,)).start()
```

I use Windows. I notice that they are run as separate processes when I wanted them to start as **subprocesses** instead. How do I make them subprocesses of the main process?

I am hesitant to use the *subprocess* module as it seems suited to run external processes (as far as I have used it).

---

**An update**: It seems Windows does not launch new processes as sub-processes. Python doesnt support getppid() (get parent's PID) in Windows.

Comment: I deindented your code. If that's wrong, feel free to revert, but please explain why that's the correct indentation. It's an immense help for prospective answerers to have a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you wall subprocess ? To me they are subprocess of your main process. Here my example and returned output.

```
import time, os
from  multiprocessing import Process

def worker():
    print "I'm process %s, my father is %s" % (os.getpid(), os.getppid())

print "I'm the main process %s" % os.getpid()
for i in range(0,3):
    Process(target=worker).start()
```

The output is :

```
I'm the main process 5897
I'm process 5898, my father is 5897
I'm process 5899, my father is 5897
I'm process 5900, my father is 5897
```

You have 3 subprocesses attached to a main process...

Comment: Wow. Your code speaks for itself. Too bad os.getppid() doesnt work on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing terminology here. A subprocess *is* a separate process. The processes that are created will be [children](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Child_process) of the main process of your program, and in that sense are subprocesses. If you want threads, then use `multithreading` instead of `multiprocessing`, but note that Python won't use multiple cores/CPUs for multiple threads.

> I am hesitant to use the `subprocess` module as it seems suited to run external processes

I'm sorry, I don't understand this remark.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x, you can also try `concurrent.futures`, which hides the more manual bits of threading.

Comment: Do you sure that Python do not use multiple cores when using multithreading?

Comment: @Pih: if a thread does a lot of work in a C extension that releases the GIL, then it may run concurrently with other threads, on a separate core. But usually, it won't. Check http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Longer:  I don't understand the question, aitchnyu.  In the typical Unix model, the only processes a process can start *are* subprocesses.  I have a strong feeling that there's a vocabulary conflict between the two of us I don't know how to unravel.  You seem to have something like an "internal process" in mind; what's an example of that, in any language or operating system?

I can attest that Python's subprocess module is widely used.

You write "... multiple working threads ..."  Have you read the documentation to which I refer in the first line at the top of this response?

Comment: I corrected it to "processes" in "multiple working threads". My bad.